# Timeout-based BufferedWriter flush

Tags: java, java-io, bufferedwriter

I'm using `BufferedWriter` with the default size of **8192** characters to write lines to a local file. The lines are read from socket inputstream using `BufferedReader` *readLine* method, blocking I/O.

Average line length is **50** characters. It all works well and fast enough (over 1 mln lines per second) however if the client stops writing, lines that are currently stored in `BufferedWriter` buffer won't be flushed to disk. In fact the buffered characters won't be flushed to disk until the client resumes writing or the connection is closed. This translates into a delay between the time line is transmitted by client and the time this line is committed to file, so long-tail latency goes up.

Is there a way to flush incomplete `BufferedWriter` buffer on timeout, e.g. within 100 milliseconds?

Comment: Can you just explicitly flush the `BufferedWriter` after each written line?

Comment: I benchmarked line-by-line flushing. Given that each line is only 50 bytes (small payload per flush), the throughput drops by half. What's worse it creates disk I/O and as such slows down other threads that are writing to files.

Comment: Fair enough, and not to beat a dead horse - but is this affect appreciable from the standpoint of a user? To quote Donald Knuth: *"Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs...premature optimization is the root of all evil"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this? It's not a *real* `BufferedWriter`, but it's a `Writer`. It works by periodically checking on on the last writer to the *underlying*, hopefully unbuffered writer, then flushing the `BufferedWriter` if it's been longer than the timeout.

```
public class PeriodicFlushingBufferedWriter extends Writer {

  protected final MonitoredWriter monitoredWriter;
  protected final BufferedWriter writer;

  protected final long timeout;
  protected final Thread thread;

  public PeriodicFlushingBufferedWriter(Writer out, long timeout) {
    this(out, 8192, timeout);
  }

  public PeriodicFlushingBufferedWriter(Writer out, int sz, final long timeout) {
    monitoredWriter = new MonitoredWriter(out);
    writer = new BufferedWriter(monitoredWriter, sz);

    this.timeout = timeout;

    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        long deadline = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(Math.max(deadline - System.currentTimeMillis(), 0));
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
          }

          synchronized (PeriodicFlushingBufferedWriter.this) {
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
              return;
            }

            long lastWrite = monitoredWriter.getLastWrite();

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastWrite >= timeout) {
              try {
                writer.flush();
              } catch (IOException e) {
              }
            }

            deadline = lastWrite + timeout;
          }
        }
      }
    });

    thread.start();
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    this.writer.write(cbuf, off, len);
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void flush() throws IOException {
    this.writer.flush();
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
    try {
      thread.interrupt();
    } finally {
      this.writer.close();
    }
  }

  private static class MonitoredWriter extends FilterWriter {

    protected final AtomicLong lastWrite = new AtomicLong();

    protected MonitoredWriter(Writer out) {
      super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int c) throws IOException {
      lastWrite.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
      super.write(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
      lastWrite.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
      super.write(cbuf, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
      lastWrite.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
      super.write(str, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
      lastWrite.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
      super.flush();
    }

    public long getLastWrite() {
      return this.lastWrite.get();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try, thanks. Another option is to store incoming lines in my own buffer and flush them on timeout with another `watcher` thread.

Answer (score 0):

@copeg is right - flush it after every line. It is easy to flush it at time period but what is the sense to have only half record and not be able to proceed it?

Answer (score 0):

You might apply Observer, Manager, and Factory patterns here and have a central BufferedWriterManager produce your BufferedWriters and maintain a list of active instances.  An internal thread might wake periodically and flush the active instances.  This might also be an opportunity for Weak references so there is no requirement for your consumers to explicitly free the object.  Instead, the GC will do the work and your Manager simply needs to handle the case when its internal reference becomes null (i.e. when all strong references are dropped).

Comment: Is flush() thread-safe? Because it's entirely possible that the BufferedWriter will trigger an implied flush and will get flushed by another thread at the same time? Neither BufferedWriter not FileWriter javadocs mention this and so I'm inclined to assume that it's not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try this complex scheme, it's too hard. Just reduce the size of the buffer, by specifying it when constructing the `BufferedWriter.` Reduce it till you find the balance between performance and latency that you need.

Comment: I have a self-imposed contract to fulfill, the message received by the server needs to be persisted to file within **100** milliseconds. If I reduce the buffer size, I won't be able to do that because the incomplete buffer won't be flushed if the client stops writing new lines.